# Creating Outlook 2010 Add in for 64bit

Tags: outlook, 64-bit, add-in, office-2010

does anyone know if there is a guide to creating an outlook add in for office 2010 that runs in 64bit mode?

I have an add in that DOES work on in Outlook 2010 32bit but it doesn't appear in 64bit - in the add in section its set to disabled.

I have tried to compile under different target CPU's but that hasn't helped..

Answer (score 4):

This: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/officedevdocs/developing-outlook-2010-solutions-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-systems) has a section on 32\64 bit compatibility.